# Request short-lived accessToken from AzureAD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

When authorising via OAUTH2 and Azure Ad the expiry of the access_token I'm receiving is set to 3599 seconds, just shy of 1h. Is there any way in to specify in the /POST request to the token endpoint, that the expiry should be less than this?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default [life time of an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes) is 1 hour. If you want to customize the expiration time (increase or decrease) of the access token, you need to use powershell to [create a token life time policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes), and then assign the policy to service principal to set up a custom token life time.